# error with status code 200 showing in console: Angular and express code attached

Tags: angular, express, routes

Im trying to delete some data and image connected to that data via an image Id using a get route (i tried the delete route but that didnt work out). My Data is now getting deleted but i get a 200 ok response beneath an error alert in chrome console(picture attached at the end). I cant figure out why so Im posting the question here.

My Setup is as follows:
Front end: Angular
Back end: Node and Express
DB: Mongo db with mongoose

For image storage and form data parsing im using multer and grid fs.

Many thanks.

Back end Routes

```
bkstwebsiteRoutes.get('/deleteSaleItem', (req, res, err) => {

  console.log(
    'sale data id ' + req.query.saleDataId 
  );

    if (saleItem.findById(req.query.saleDataId)) {

    saleItem.findByIdAndDelete(req.query.saleDataId, () => {
      res.send(
        'sale Item Data pertaining to ID ' +
          req.query.saleDataId +
          ' was found and deleted'
      );
    });
  } else if (!saleItem.findById(req.query.saleDataId)) {
    res.send(
      'sale Item Data pertaining to ID ' +
        req.query.saleDataId +
        ' does not exist'
    );
  } else {
    res.send('unknown server error: ' + err);
  }


});

// route to delete image
bkstwebsiteRoutes.get('/deleteSaleImage', (req, res, err) => {
  if (gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.query.imageId })) {

    gfs.files.deleteOne({ filename: req.query.imageId }, () => {
      res.send(
        'the image of the sale item  with its own id of ' +
          req.query.imageId +
          ' was found and successfully deleted'
      );
    });
  } else if (!gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.query.imageId })) {
    res.send(
      'the image of the sale item with id with its own id of ' +
        req.query.imageId +
        ' does not exist'
    );
  } else {
    res.send('unknown server error: ' + err);
  }
});
```

Angular Service Code

```
 deleteSaleItem(saleDataId, imageId) {
    const saleDataCallString =
      this.backendUri + '/deleteSaleItem?saleDataId=' + saleDataId;

    const saleImageCallString =
      this.backendUri + '/deleteSaleImage?imageId=' + imageId;
    this.http.get(saleDataCallString).subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
    });
    this.http.get(saleImageCallString).subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
```

[image: picture of the error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I simply set up json objects at the back end with key value pairs with res.json and this error went away. If someone runs in to this and wants a detailed answer I'll be happy to help.